# Best way to reach nested method via string

Tags: javascript, dynamic, interpolation

I want to programmatically reach a method that is nested inside a object.

```
var app = {
    property:{
        method:function(){},
        property:"foo"
    }    
}
```

Normally you would access it like so: `app.property.method`

But in my case, In runtime I get a string that I want to interpolate that into calling the `method` function

Now, how can `method` be accessed programmatically when i have the following string

```
"app.property.method"
```

​
For a reference please see:
http://jsfiddle.net/adardesign/92AnA/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A while ago I wrote this little script to get an object from the string describing its path:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    if (!Object.fromPath) {
        Object.fromPath = function (context, path) {
            var result,
                keys,
                i;
            //if called as `Object.fromPath('foo.bar.baz')`,
            //assume `window` as context
            if (arguments.length < 2) {
                path = context;
                context = window;
            }
            //start at the `context` object
            result = context;
            //break the path on `.` characters
            keys = String(path).split('.');
            //`!= null` is being used to break out of the loop
            //if `null` or `undefined are found
            for (i = 0; i < keys.length && result != null; i+= 1) {
                //iterate down the path, getting the next part
                //of the path each iteration
                result = result[keys[i]];
            }
            //return the object as described by the path,
            //or null or undefined if they occur anywhere in the path
            return result;
        };
    }
}());
```

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to use bracket notation (i'd avoid the other option - `eval()`). If the `app` variable is global, then it would be a property of the `window` object:

```
executeFunctionByName("app.property.method", window);
```

Method borrowed from: [How to execute a JavaScript function when I have its name as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359788/how-to-execute-a-javascript-function-when-i-have-its-name-as-a-string)

The method essentially just breaks your `window["app.property.method"]` (which would fail) into `window["app"]["property"]["method"]` (which works).

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for, i wanted to roll my own solution, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
var methodString = "app.property.method";

var method = eval(methodString);
```

Then method will be a function pointer which may be called like so:

```
method();
```